# Ruby metaprogramming: instance_eval and class_eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Seems I am confused between the two methods though I have been using them for a while, I can't understand why the method *passengers* is not being added to the object in the following code:

```
class Bus
  def number_of_seats
    42
  end
end

Bus.class_eval do
  define_method :number_of_windows do
    number_of_seats
  end

  def fuel_type
    :diesel
  end
end

Bus.instance_eval do
  define_method :destination do
    'Paris'
  end

  def passengers
    12
  end
end

bus = Bus.new
bus.number_of_windows # => 42
bus.fuel_type # => :diesel
bus.destination # => "Paris"
bus.passengers # => undefined method `passengers' (NoMethodError)
```

**Notes**:

- Tried `instance_eval` first, just randomly used `class_eval` and then it too seemed to work!
- My understanding of `instance_eval`'s block: The code in the block is run with `self` set to the object calling `instance_eval`.
- My understanding of `class_eval`'s block: The code in the block is evaluated as if its placed by opening the class of the object calling it. Hence I am puzzled at the `class_eval` in the above case! I was expecting `class_eval` on *Bus* would mean evaluating the block in the `class` of *Bus Class*.

Comment: The method `passengers` works fine: `Bus.passengers #=> 12`. Change   `Bus.instance_eval` to  `Bus.class_eval` to make `passengers` an instance method.

Comment: You could also use `Bus.send(:define_method, :passengers) { 12 }`.

Comment: Apart from 'how things work', this is definitely very weird behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer [this](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval) awesome article on class and `instance_eval` as to why *passengers* is not being added to the object.

TL;DR:

**`Bus.class_eval will` create instance methods and `Bus.instance_eval` will create class methods.**

Now, regarding the behavior of *destination*(which could be called on instance).....**define method when used inside either `class_eval` or `instance_eval` is immune to the usual behaviour**. Why?.

Because the documentation says so. As per the documentation:

> define method - Defines an instance method in the receiver.

Therefore, it does not matter if you use `define_method` inside `class_eval` or `instance_eval` it would always create an instance method.

[Source for reference.](http://www.ploughthroughruby.co.uk/2009/09/30/define_method-instance_eval-and-class_eval.html)

Hope this helped :-).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do an `instance_eval` on a class object when using `def`. Here's a general way you use `instance_eval` and `class_eval`. http://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-winter15/classEval.php